# GMSPolygon zIndex not working?

Tags: ios, overlay, z-index, tap

Using the latest Google Maps iOS SDK I have a map with overlapping Polygon area's. When trying to tap them, the

`- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView  didTapOverlay: (GMSOverlay *) overlay`

function does not loop thru all overlays. 
Trying to set the zIndex value to a higher value doesn't seem to make any difference. The value is set, but still I cannot tap the other overlapped overlay..

Anyone has found the same problem? or maybe has another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug in google maps iOS SDK. Fixed now.